# How to check if database is empty in SQLite Android with DatabaseConnector class

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a DatabaseConnector class where I want to check if the database is empty and then show an alert and a click on it will close the activity.

This is my DatabaseConnector class

```
public class DatabaseConnector {

    // Declare Variables
    private static final String DB_NAME = "MyNotes";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tablenotes";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String NOTE = "note";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbOpenHelper;
    public static final String MAINCAT = "maincat";
    public static final String SUBCAT = "subcat";

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, DB_NAME, null,
                DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    // Open Database function
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        // Allow database to be in writable mode
        database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Close Database function
    public void close() {
        if (database != null)
            database.close();
    }

    // Create Database function
    public void InsertNote(String title, String note , String maincat, String subcat) {
        ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
        newCon.put(TITLE, title);
        newCon.put(NOTE, note);
        newCon.put(MAINCAT,  maincat);
        newCon.put(SUBCAT, subcat);

        open();
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newCon);
        close();
    }

    // Update Database function
    public void UpdateNote(long id, String title, String note) {
        ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
        editCon.put(TITLE, title);
        editCon.put(NOTE, note);

        open();
        database.update(TABLE_NAME, editCon, ID + "=" + id, null);
        close();
    }

    // Delete Database function
    public void DeleteNote(long id) {
        open();
        database.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=" + id, null);
        close();
    }

    // List all data function
    //String selection = dbOpenHelper.MAINCAT + " = 'quiz'"  
       //     +" AND " + dbOpenHelper.SUBCAT + " = 'test'";

//  public Cursor ListAllNotes() {
//      return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { ID, TITLE }, null,
//              null, null, null, TITLE);
//  }

    public Cursor ListAllNotes(String selection) {
        return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { ID, TITLE }, selection,
                null, null, null, TITLE);
    }



    // Capture single data by ID
    public Cursor GetOneNote(long id) {
        return database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, ID + "=" + id, null, null,
                null, null);
    }
```

And here is the ListActivity wherein I want to close the Activity with an alert

```
public class dbMainactivty extends ListActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private ListView noteListView;
    private CursorAdapter noteAdapter;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("dbMainactivty");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        // Locate ListView
        noteListView = getListView();
        //  setContentView(R.layout.list_note);
        //noteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
        noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

        // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { TITLE };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

        // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
        noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(dbMainactivty.this,
                R.layout.list_note, null, from, to);

        // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
        setListAdapter(noteAdapter);


    }


    // Capture ListView item click
    OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // Open ViewNote activity
            Intent viewnote = new Intent(dbMainactivty.this, ViewNote.class);

            // Pass the ROW_ID to ViewNote activity
            viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
            startActivity(viewnote);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
        new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

        // Deactivates the Cursor
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();

        noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Intent i = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
                        String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent2);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);


        case R.id.action_share:
            i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, feed.getItem(pos).getTitle().toString()+ " to know the answer download http://developer.android.com/index.html");
            i.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(i);
            return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    };


    // GetNotes AsyncTask
    private class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(dbMainactivty.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // Open the database
            dbConnector.open();

            return dbConnector.ListAllNotes("maincat LIKE 'quiz' AND subcat LIKE 'test'");


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);

            // Close Database
            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(
                    "Please check your Internet Connection.")
                    .setTitle("tilte")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            //loader.cancel(true);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });


            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();

        } else {
            Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();
            if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                //do your action
                //Fetch your data
                GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStart(this);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yipeee!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(
                        "oops nothing pinned yet!   ....")
                        .setTitle("title")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                //loader.cancel(true);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });


                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }  

        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to check

`cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0` and if it turns false then show the alert that 
`nothing has been pinned yet` 
Should show up however even though if the cursor returns data the alert still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, take a look at the lifecycle of your activity: http://www.android-app-market.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

As you can see onResume() is called after onStart() which means that checking the cursor on the onStart() can not work.

Secondly you are starting an AsyncTask (GetNotes) on the onResume() method which means you are running a parallel thread at this point and can't check for the result after calling new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);

Your problem is you need to check the emptiness of your cursor (`cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0`) AFTER the data is loader which mean after the AsyncTask has completed. In other words, move the check for emptiness on your cursor inside the `onPostExecute(Cursor result)` method.